# xmlXPathCompOpEval: function function not found

Tags: php, function, xslt

I'm getting an error:

> Warning: `XSLTProcessor::transformToXml()`: `xmlXPathCompOpEval`: function function not found in ...

PHP Code:

```
$this->proc=new XSLTProcessor;
$this->proc->registerPHPFunctions();

if (!$this->proc->importStylesheet($new_xslt)) throw new Exception('XSLT content cannot load');

if (!$data=$this->proc->transformToXml($this->xml_dom)) {
    throw new Exception('XML changing with XSLT error unknow');
}
```

XSL template:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl" >
        <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
                    doctype-system="http://www.w3c.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd"/>
        <xsl:include href="default.xsl"/>
        <xsl:variable name="start"/>
        <xsl:template match="/response">
            <html>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="headers"/>
                <body>

                    <div class="body" id="body">
                        <xsl:call-template name="main.block">
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </div>
                    <div align="center" class="copy">©
                        <xsl:value-of select="php:function('date', 'Y')"/> here should be date
                    </div>
                </body>
            </html>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Also tried in this way with extension-element-prefixes and xsl:namespace-alias:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl"
                    xsl:extension-element-prefixes="php">
        <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
                    doctype-system="http://www.w3c.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd"/>
        <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="php" result-prefix="xsl"/>
        <xsl:include href="default.xsl"/>
        <xsl:variable name="start"/>
        <xsl:template match="/response">
            <html>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="headers"/>
                <body>

                    <div class="body" id="body">
                        <xsl:call-template name="main.block">
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </div>
                    <div align="center" class="copy">©
                        <xsl:value-of select="php:function('date', 'Y')"/> here should be date
                    </div>
                </body>
            </html>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

If I remove php function from template I see no errors.

This code looks okay and working on webserver with php 5.3 but does not work on my local pc with php 5.6

All other things are working ok, the trouble only with php function in xsl template.

@upd: Also tried different versions of php on my pc: 5.3, 5.4, 5.5 - the result is same. I have Mac OS X.

Comment: Can you show a minimal but complete stylesheet creating the problem? When I google for that error message it seems there is one old thread that used `<xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="php" result-prefix="xsl" />`, I am not sure whether that can cause the problem but it looks like the only oddity in the code.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I updated question body

Comment: @MartinHonnen Also simple example from http://php.net/manual/ru/xsltprocessor.registerphpfunctions.php shows the same error.